# How can I make the Odoo delivery address show inline on the order?

Tags: odoo

The partner_id has a context

```
{'show_address': 1}
```

Which I thought made the address show inline, but setting the context doesn't seem to accomplish the same thing on partner_shipping_id

```
<field name="partner_shipping_id" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="context">{'show_address':1,'default_type':'delivery'}</attribute>
</field>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I also need to make it always reload as the address is pulled in dynamically.

```
<field name="partner_shipping_id" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="context">{'show_address':1,'default_type':'delivery'}</attribute>
  <attribute name="options">{"always_reload": True}</attribute>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right you missed

> always_reload

Since the web client has already sent the record with a value it will not call **name_get** method. so the **always_reload** option in Many2one field forces to call name_get method explicitly